# Xcode 11, -[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, appdelegate, xcode11

I am using Xcode 11.
How to get "window" object? Before Xcode update I was using this:

> [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].bounds

Comment: you can get the keyWindow using  `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: I needed to get frame of "window", and I was using this.
view.frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].bounds

But now i'm getting this error, because there is SceneDelegate and AppDelegate.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: thanks, [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject]